# Reading objects from a binary file

Tags: c++, file, binary

I wrote a program, which lets you enter information about a car, and then writes the object on a binary file.

```
Car car_obj; std::ofstream entr; std::ifstream ex; 
void save_data() {

entr.open("main.bin", std::ios::app | std::ios::binary);

    car_obj.setInfo(); entr.write((char*)&car_obj, sizeof (car_obj));

entr.close();
```

}

After this, I have a function which is reading this binary file in order to display all cars which have fuel consumption less than what the user enters (the number is factr in the function arguments).

```
void vehicles_under_factr(float factr) {

ex.open("main.bin", std::ios::app | std::ios::binary);


while (ex.read((char*)&car_obj, sizeof (car_obj)) && !ex.eof()) {

    if (car_obj.fuel_cons < factr) {

        car_obj.displayInfo();

    }
} 

ex.close();
```

}

It works fine, but only if I have three, or less, objects in my binary file. When there are more than three, it displays the rest as empty fields. As if there is no access after the third car. Why is that so, and what can I do about it?

I feel close to the solution, but my knowledge is limited. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're going to have to provide a small but complete sample of code that exhibits your problem.   Since you're working with binary files, it would probably help if that code writes out a set of objects and then makes an attempt to read them in.   Otherwise, people will just be guessing about what is contributing to your problem.

Comment: How `Car` classes memory layout actually looks? You probably can't do what you want, because of serializing pointers.

Comment: It probably doesn't help that your reading code is opening the file in append mode (which means it opens at the end, rather than the beginning) and that you are looping on `ex.eof()` [So the code will attempt to read starting at the end, and then test for EOF].

Comment: Oh god, Peter was right, thank you! That was such a stupid mistake I didn't see...

Comment: If you are trying open the file on another computer, read about [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Although, I don't think this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

no， you can't do this，read（（char *）obj, sizeof(obj)）,because every object in program have itself memory address, allocate by system. you can't read address
from file .if your object only contain data, it work fine, but if it's element is a object and itself attribute related memory address or iterator(related memory address). it work fail.